# Ho to convert Saml2SecurityToken to XML form?

Tags: xml, .net-4.5, wif, saml

I am working with WIF and I create an instance of  `Saml2SecurityToken`, now I would like to save this token as XML, so that I can use it in testing - I cannot see obvious way of doing it however.

I have seen [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/34b326e5-504f-4b76-9803-a67eab547d19/saml2securitytoken-to-xmlelement?forum=Geneva) answer that suggest using `SecurityTokenHandler` however this class has a protected constructor, so I cannot just new it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me, I should have been using `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` 
rather than just `SecurityTokenHandler` which is an abstract class.

This solved my problem:

```
 public static void DupmToken(Saml2SecurityToken token)
 {
     var handler = new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler();
     var sw = new StringWriter();
     handler.WriteToken(new XmlTextWriter(sw), token);
     Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
 }
```